# SQL Insert with Inner Join trying to insert into wrong column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing table of products, and I'm trying to insert new attributes from other tables into my main product table.

Here's my query:

```
INSERT INTO company_attributes (amp)
    SELECT company_attr_amperage.amp
        FROM company_attr_amperage
        INNER JOIN company_attributes
        ON company_attr_amperage.product_id = company_attributes.product_id;
```

The error that I get is: Field 'product_id' doesn't have a default value.

I'm not trying to insert into the product_id column, I'm trying to insert into the amp column (as specified on row 1 of the query)

The amp column exists on the company_attributes table, but right now, every value is NULL

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Are you trying to `INSERT` a new record or `UPDATE` existing one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just want to *update* the value in existing rows.  If so:

```
UPDATE company_attributes ca JOIN
       company_attr_amperage caa
       ON caa.product_id = ca.product_id
    SET ca.amp = caa.amp;
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT`'s job is to put new rows into a table, in your case `company_attributes`. Those new rows must be valid. Your table definition says that there's no default value for a column called `product_id` in that table. So, MySQL doesn't know what to put into that column when you don't provide it with your `INSERT` operation.

So, when you insert a row you *must* provide a value for that column.

There's no way to put a value into a column without creating a row for it, or `UPDATE`ing an existing row.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff. Your answer did it